# Trying to change the authentication fields in devise for rails to username

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm trying to modify devise to use the username field instead of email to authenticate. I've already added the username attribute and I can successfully login with the username for an existing user, but for some reason now when i try to register a new user, I get an error "Email can't be blank".

My devise form has fields for both email and username.

I followed instructions here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-with-something-other-than-their-email-address with the exception that I'm on rails 4, so attr_accessible has been deprecated. Is there something else that needs to be done here in rails 4?

I'm not sure where to start looking to start debugging this or if I need to generate the devise controllers..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case, anyone comes across the issue, I was able to figure this out myself. Per the devise documentation on [Strong Parameters](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#user-content-strong-parameters), the sign_up method will permit only the authentication keys + password/password confirmation. So we have to tell it to permit :email as will, but this can be done in the application controller.

The code below is mostly from the same devise documentation, so you can read more about it there. We can use a before filter to permit whatever non-authentication keys you might need.

```html
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :email
  end
end
```